# How do I specify SMTP server for an e-mail in PHP?

Tags: php, email

I want to send an e-mail through a PHP script in Linux. My code is as follows:

```
$to = $row['EmailID'];
$subject = "XYZ";
$message = "yes!!!!";
$from = "pallav123goyal@gmail.com";
if(!mail($to,$subject,$message,"From:" . $from))
{
 echo "Confirmation E-mail couldn't be sent to " . $row['EmailID'] . "<br>";
}
 else
{
 echo "Confirmation E-mail sent to " . $row['EmailID'] . "<br>";
}
```

On running the code, the else part of the above code is executed as evident from its output. But no e-mail gets sent to $row['EmailID'] (which is a valid email ID)

I was told that I must specify an SMTP server for the mail. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your SMTP server in your php.ini file

Check this thread for example: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10307560-CONFIGURING-php-ini-%28Setting-the-SMTP%29!!!

If you want to do it inline, you can try changing these settings with ini_set();

Comment: I don't have any such file. Do I need to make one?

Comment: PHP.INI is part of your PHP installation. Try executing `phpinfo();` ... You will get a table that amongst many other things, shows you where the php.ini is that is being used.

Comment: Okay, but I still don't understand. What do I need to change in the file? Which host are you talking about? Which port?

Comment: You want to specify an SMTP , right? SMTP is a service that runs on a server. The server has a hostname or IP address. And the SMTP service is running on a specific port number. Now, these data (hostname, portnumber) you need to set in php.ini. Just like you can see in the link I have in my answer.

Comment: All right. I forgot to mention. I don't know what SMTP means. I tried to google, but I couldn't understand.

Comment: You only asked how to specify the SMTP server... So that is my answer. But if you want to know what an SMTP server is... : An SMTP server is a service (program) what other programs (such as PHP service) use to send e-mail. PHP for example talks to the SMTP server and tells it to send the e-mail. The SMTP server then takes care of delivering the email. If you are running Linux, chances are you already have an SMTP server running on `localhost` on port `25`. Otherwise, you can use your ISP's SMTP server or your e-mail provider's SMTP server. They should give you: host, port, username, password.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10307560-CONFIGURING-php-ini-(Setting-the-SMTP)!!!

smtp=
*the name of the host where the SMTP server you'll be using is running (whoever's responsible for your network connection should know this)*
smtp_port=
*the port on that host the SMTP server is listening on (25 is the conventional choice)*
sendmail_from=
*the email address that the sent mail should say it's from*

Just configure the above in your php.ini file.

**[Edit]** to reflect my comment:- if you dont have access to the default php.ini file, you can create one in your webroot and drop this in.

**[Edit 2]** This does depend on the configuation on the server, most hosts will allow it however.

Comment: if you dont have access to the default php.ini, you can make one in your web root and just drop this in.

Comment: You cannot make a php.ini in your webroot (as you state in comment) and have it get used. Maybe you meant .htaccess . Also your answer (and the link in your answer) is exactly the same as mine :)

Comment: i think you'll find you can :)

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php

it does depend on configuration, but most hosts allow it.

Comment: I don't know what SMTP means. What server or port are we talking about?

Comment: was just reviwing old answers @nl-x you're right, same answer and link heh. user2956287 if this is resolved can you accept an answer?