# How to send emails via SMTP?

Tags: php

I don't know what SMTP is. I just wanna send an email through a PHP file. Do I need to download any SMTP software for it? And what is meant by the SMTP server and port?

Comment: Please don't open multiple threads with the same questions ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841081/how-do-i-specify-smtp-server-for-an-e-mail-in-php/19841140?noredirect=1#comment29505658_19841140

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Googling for `PHP send email` reveals that.

Comment: I followed the same procedure as given in your link. Doesn't seem to work